# bash alias containing while do loop gives unexpected token error

Tags: bash, while-loop, alias

When I run this command in bash it works fine:

```
$ while sleep 1; do mysqladmin proc | grep tbl1; done
```

But, when I add it to my .bash_aliases or just run:

```
$ alias loop='while sleep 1; do $@; done'
```

It produces this error (using `ls` as an example):

```
$ loop ls
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ls'
```

My goal is to incorporate this loop command as an alias into my shell so I can use it more frequently.  I've tried escaping it different ways, including double quotes, single quotes, `${$@}` and more.

Comment: Thank you @that other guy   -- I did try searching but couldn't find the answer for whatever reason.  I tested your answer and it works fine!  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: No problem, it's hard to search. Check out [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) which automatically detects common issues including this one ("Aliases can't use positional parameters. Use a function.")

Comment: Note: even with a function, you can't pass a pipeline, just a simple command. For example, `loop mysqladmin proc | grep tbl1` will run the equivalent of `while sleep 1; do mysqladmin proc; done | grep tbl1` (which probably works, at least in this case, but might not be what you expect).